# Re-write do-while loop with continue statement using Java Streams

Tags: java, functional-programming

I am trying to re-write following code with Functional Java. str is a pipe | and equal = delimited string where it contains FieldName1=FieldValue1|FieldName2=FieldValue2|... and so on... This code find first occurrence of fieldname and the find corresponding value split by = sign. Is there any way to handle continue using Functional Java?

Same fieldname could present multiple time in input string and due to that need to start reading it after a particular index.
String str in input is big so not sure if it is a good idea to split complete string before processing it using Stream?

**Sample input**
str=Bond=US922646AS37|Isin=US922646AS37|Cusip=922646AS3|Price=100.5|Currency=USD|Position=2000000|.......|Bond=US69318FAJ75|Isin=US69318FAJ75|Cusip=69318FAJ7|Price=102.5|Currency=USD|Position=1000000|.....

fieldName=Price

startIdx=100

**output**: 102.5

```
String process(String fieldName, int startIdx, String str) {
        do {
            int start = str.indexOf(fieldName, startIdx);
            if (start == -1) {
                return null;
            }
            if ( start > 0 && str.charAt(start-1) != '|' ) {
                startIdx = start+1;
                continue;
            }
            int val = str.indexOf("=", start);
            if ( val == -1 ) {
                return null;
            }
            if (val - fieldName.length() != start) {
                int end = str.indexOf("|", startIdx);
                if (end == -1) {
                    return null; 
                }
                start = end + 1;
                continue;
            }
            int end = str.indexOf("|", val);
            if (end == -1) {
               return str.substring(val + 1);
            } else {
              return str.substring(val + 1, end);
            }
    } while (true);
}
```

Comment: Please provide an input and expected output for some examples.  It looks like you may wan to create a map.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated question with input and output. Same fieldname could present multiple time in input string and due to that need to start reading it after a particular index.

Comment: With the irregular boundaries of fields and values how do you know what starting index to use?   Do you want all the fields for a particular field name or just the first encountered?

Comment: This method is called many times and when find a field in string then next field will be later than previous one. It seems it is not easy to move away from use of continue.  This string is more than 50K characters so not sure it is a good idea to split it in front before handover to stream.

Comment: Now I understand. What about the special case of "str=" at the beginning? what if you specify "str" as the field and 0as the index. Do the values always terminate with a vertical bar or do the fields all start with a vertical bar?

Comment: Hi WJS, thanks for you answer. It seems I created more confusion. "str=" is not part of input. I just want to put str="Bond=US922646AS37|Isin=US922646AS37|Cusip=922646AS3|Price=100.5|Currency=USD|Position=2000000|.......|Bond=US69318FAJ75|Isin=US69318FAJ75|Cusip=69318FAJ7|Price=102.5|Currency=USD|Position=1000000|.....".  It is representing input value of str argument of given method.

Comment: No problem.  I think I have what you want or at a minimum provides some ideas.  This uses a stream supplied by use of the `Pattern class`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

- create a record (class) to hold the information
- first split on the pipe.
- then split on the equals sign.  This puts the arrays of field/value pairs on the stream.
- then create an instance of Item and place it in a list.

```
record Item ( String name, String value) {}

String s = """
Bond=US922646AS37|Isin=US922646AS37|Cusip=922646AS3|\
Price=100.5|Currency=USD|Position=2000000|\
Bond=US69318FAJ75|Isin=US69318FAJ75|\
Cusip=69318FAJ7|Price=102.5|Currency=USD|Position=1000000\
""";

List<Item> items =  Arrays.stream(s.split("\\|")).map(str -> str.split("="))
        .map(arr->new Item(arr[0], arr[1])).toList();
        
items.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
Item[name=Bond, value=US922646AS37]
Item[name=Isin, value=US922646AS37]
Item[name=Cusip, value=922646AS3]
Item[name=Price, value=100.5]
Item[name=Currency, value=USD]
Item[name=Position, value=2000000]
Item[name=Bond, value=US69318FAJ75]
Item[name=Isin, value=US69318FAJ75]
Item[name=Cusip, value=69318FAJ7]
Item[name=Price, value=102.5]
Item[name=Currency, value=USD]
Item[name=Position, value=1000000]
```

**Updated Answer.**

- first, construct a regex

  - `fieldName`
  - `=`
  - followed by a capture group.

    - `(.*?)` - reluctant match
    - `(?:\\||$)` = followed by a non-capture group specifying the end being either a vertical bar or end of string.
- Then start matching at the index of the string.
- Returning `matchresults`, get capture `group 1` and return that value or null if no match found

```
static String process(String fieldName, int startIdx, String str) {
     String regex = new StringBuilder(fieldName)
             .append("=").append("(.*?)(?:\\||$)").toString();
    return  Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str.substring(startIdx))
  .results().map(mr->mr.group(1)).findFirst().orElse(null); 
}
```

I also took your approach with some modifications. This would be my preferred approach as it is more efficient, since it avoids the overhead of streams and regular expressions. It would be even simpler if the input string ended with a '|'.

```
static String process(String fieldName, int startIdx, String str) {
    fieldName += "=";
    int fidx = str.indexOf(fieldName, startIdx);
  
    if (fidx < 0) {
        return null;
    }
    int flen = fieldName.length();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = fidx + flen; i < str.length() && str.charAt(i) != '|'; i++) {
       sb.append(str.charAt(i));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: sorry.. I have updated question with input and output. same field may present multiple time. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
public void getValue(InputStream inputStream, char lineSep, char valueSep, String key, int startIdx, Consumer<String> callback){
    new Thread(() -> {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            int c;
            int i = 0;
            while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1){
                if (i++ > startIdx) {
                    if (c == lineSep) {
                        String[] split = builder.toString().split(String.valueOf(valueSep));
                        if (split.length == 2 && split[0].equals(key)){
                            callback.accept(split[1]);
                            break;
                        }
                        builder = new StringBuilder();
                        continue;
                    }
                    builder.append(c);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Example:

```
getValue(i, '|', '=', "price", 100, (Consumer<String>) value -> System.out.println("Value is " + value));
```

If your input is a string:

```
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(yourString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: Hi G Dias, thanks for answer. However same field can present multiple time and need to consider field only after a particular index in String. Above solution will not work because it will not give option to choose field value after particular index.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get it rigth. Here's a new answer, hope it works!